# Ruby - define_method and closures

Tags: ruby, reflection, closures, self

define_method exhibits the following behaviour:

```
class TestClass
  def exec_block(&block) ; yield ; end
end
TestClass.new.send(:exec_block) do ; puts self ; end
# -> main
TestClass.send(:define_method, :bing) do ; puts self ; end
TestClass.new.bing
# -> <TestClass:...>
```

What I do not understand is that the the block passed to define_method is supposed to be a closure. As such it should (at least according to my understanding) capture the value of `self` as `main`, as exhibited when calling `exec_block`.

I understand that the block will become the body of the method, yet I do not understand the reason for the behavior. Why does the block evaluate to different things when used with different methods ?

How can I reproduce the behavior of block with `define_method` for other methods ? i.e. how could I write `exec_block` to have it output `<TestClass:...>` instead of `main´ ?

Comment: How do you explain the behavior of exec_block then ? It should print `main` if `self` was not captured. Or do I miss something ?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the opposite of what I tought. The fact is that it does print `main`, if it was not captured, it should print `<TestClass:...>` which is not the case.

Comment: Nice ! But if the self is dynamically bound, shouldn't it print `TestClass` is the `exec_block` case ? Since the block gets called by `yield whitin `TestClass`. Actually, I'm not quite clear on what happens when Ruby reads the definition of the block. Is any information saved about `self` saved, for instance ? (Also, if you would summarize your comments in an answer, I would accept it.)

Comment: Apparently I got this wrong by myself. `self` *is* captured in the closure, but `define_method` and `(instance|module)_(eval|exec)` dynamically bind it to a new value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self` is captured by the closure like any other variable. We can verify that by passing a `Proc` around different object instances:

```
class A
  def exec_block(&block)
    block.call
  end
end

class B
  def exec_indirect(&block)
    A.new.exec_block(&block)
  end
end

block = proc { p self }
a = A.new; b = B.new

a.exec_block(&block)    # => main
b.exec_indirect(&block) # => main
```

However, [`BasicObject#instance_eval`](http://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/instance_eval) and the alikes rebind the `self` variable dynamically:

> In order to set the context, the variable `self` is set to *obj* while the code is executing, giving the code access to *obj’s* instance variables

[`Module#define_method`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method) in turn uses `instance_eval` to execute the associated block:

> If a block is specified, it is used as the method body. This block is evaluated using instance_eval [...]

Observe:

```
A.send(:define_method, :foo, &block)
a.foo                   # => #<A:0x00000001717040>
a.instance_eval(&block) # => #<A:0x00000001717040>
```

With that knowledge, you can now rewrite your `exec_block` to use `instance_eval`:

```
class A
  def exec_block(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

block = proc { p self }
A.new.exec_block(&block)  # => #<A:0x00000001bb9828>
```

As mentioned before, using `instance_eval` seems to be the only way to run a `Proc` instance with a modified context. It can be used to [implement dynamic binding](https://github.com/niklasb/ruby-dynamic-binding) in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

First thing - when you passing a block explicitly to the method instead of `yield` you can use `block.call`.
Second thing - inside `exec_block` method replace `yield` with `instance_eval(&block)` and you will see the magic ;)

Little bit more clarification - in the first example the block catches the local scope along with `self` variable which is pointing to `main` object.

In the second example (with `define_method`) the block will be treated as a new method body and it will be evaluated inside object's scope using `instance_eval`. For more details you can check: http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method

Comment: So what you are saying is that the meaning of `self` is not fixed when the block is defined. To put it otherwise, `self` is not lexically scoped. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired on the comment of Niklas B.:

```
class TestClass
  def exec_block(&block) ; yield ; end
end
s = self

TestClass.new.send(:exec_block) do ; puts s ; end
# -> main

TestClass.send(:define_method, :bing) do ; puts s ; end
TestClass.new.bing
# -> main
```